# django uwsgi no app loaded

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

Have a troubles with uwsgi and django project on Ubuntu 12.04.
uwsgi runs fine but see no apps.

My project is located in **/home/satchitananda/PycharmProjects/dbTest/** directory.

**nginx config:**

```
server {
root /usr/share/nginx/www;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name somehost;


location / {
            uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/app/projectname/socket;
            include uwsgi_params;
}


location /doc {
    root /usr/share;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}
}
```

**uwsgi config:**

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python27
virtualenv=/home/satchitananda/.env4/
pythonpath = ..
thread=3
master=1
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=dbTest.dbTest.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
chdir = /home/satchitananda/PycharmProjects/dbTest/
#socket = /var/run/uwsgi/app/projectname/socket
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/projectname.log
touch-reload = /home/satchitananda/PycharmProjects/dbTest/
```

**uwsgi log:**

```
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - *** Starting uWSGI 1.0.3-debian (64bit) on [Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012] ***
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 17 July 2012 02:26:54
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - current working directory: /
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/projectname/pid
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - setgid() to 33
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - setuid() to 33
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/projectname/socket fd 5
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 22335)
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 22337, cores: 1)
Thu Aug 16 09:29:57 2012 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 22339, cores: 1)
```

How to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You disable socket with # now it is a comment

```
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/app/projectname/socket
```

I'm not sure, but default project settings looks like `dbTest.settings` not `dbTest.dbTest.settings`

```
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=dbTest.settings
```